# 'Must declare the scalar variable "@img".'

Tags: sql, vb.net, image, scalar

I need your help please. 
I have a user form in vb.net using sql database my query is work properly but when I use @img for insert employee image I get the error "must declare scalar variable"
What should I do?

```
  Public Sub ExecuteMyQuery(MyCommand As SqlCommand, MyMessage As String)

        con.Open()

        If MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery = 1 Then

            MessageBox.Show(MyMessage)

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Query Not Execute")

        End If

        con.Close()

    End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim ms As New MemoryStream

        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)

        Dim img() As Byte

        img = ms.ToArray()

        Dim insertquery As String = ("Insert into AddNew(EmpID,EmpSalary,EmpImage) values(" & EmpID.Text_

& "," & EmpSalary.Text & ",@img)")

        Dim command As New SqlCommand(insertquery, con)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img

        ExecuteMyQuery(command, "Image Inserted")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Please i need your help please.i have a user form in vb.net using sql database my query is work properly but when i use @img for insert employee image then show me error must declare scalar variable please tell me any one what i do?

Comment: You are using different command objects in the last handler. `cmd` and `command`

Comment: Thanks Dear now its work properly done.again thanks you are really genius man.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img
```

So it reads:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img
```